# Xcode 8 beta - How do you change the size of all the viewcontrollers in storyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I was previously using xcode 7.3 and just upgraded to xcode 8 beta but in the process the sizes of all my viewcontrollers on storyboard went from a wider (iphone 6 plus type of size) to a narrower (iphone 6 type of size). This has really messed with my constraints and I was wondering how do I change the size back? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the picture of the current view controller size in Xcode 8 beta
[image]

[image]

Comment: Select the device type at the bottom of the window

Comment: @Paulw11 on second look, this did NOT solve my problem as it keeps defaulting to iphone 6 size when I open it up

Comment: It may be a bug.  It changes back to iPhone 6 and there doesn't seem to be a way to change that default.

Answer (score 8):

As of XCode 8, at the bottom right, select View As: (and then the device you want)

[image: View As]

Answer (score 4):

From here you can set/select all the screen sizes available [image: All screen size]

Comment: that doesn't exist on xcode 8, please look at my edit (includes picture)

Comment: For the Xcode 8 you can select the device from bottom and the orientation in which you want to change the constraints.